# Iterating through two arrays with a correlation and getting the sum Numpy Python

Tags: python, arrays, function, numpy, iteration

I am trying to modify the code down below so that it adds up the `indexes` and the `Numbers` values that correlate with it.

So since the first element in `indexes` is 3, it takes the first 3 elements within `Numbers` which is `1, 5, 6` sum of all these integers is equal to 12.

For the second value in the next 5 elements is being computed `7,4,3,6,7` which is equal to 27.

I am trying to achieve `Expected Output` but am getting the `Current Output` what can I change in the code to achieve the `Expected Output` without using a for loop.

```
Numbers = np.array([1, 5, 6,7,4,3,6,7,11,3,4,6,2,20])
indexes = np.array([3 , 5, 5])
np.add.reduceat(Numbers, indexes)
```

Current Output:

```
array([11,  3, 62])
```

Expected Output

```
array([12, 27, 26])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
np.add.reduceat(Numbers, [0,3,3,8,8,13])[::2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Pair indices by cumulative sum and then provide it to `reduceat`

```
pair_indexes = np.insert(
    indexes.cumsum(), 0, 0
).repeat([1] + [2] * (len(indexes) - 1) + [1])

np.add.reduceat(Numbers, pair_indexes)[::2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Adjust your "indexes" variable to represent bins rather than increments.

```
Numbers = np.array([1, 5, 6,7,4,3,6,7,11,3,4,6,2,20])
indexes = np.array([0, 3 , 8, 13])

answ = np.add.reduceat(Numbers, indexes)[:-1]
```